How can I migrate a project installed as a package?
I have a project as a package that contains IDbContext and DbContext and I want to install it in different projects and migrate to and use it. How can I do this?
My package is AlirezaFlh.AudiLogging
This is config for another project:
builder.Services.AddAuditLogging(options =>
{
    options.EnableOldValues = true; //optional
    options.EnableNewValues = true; //optional
    options.ConfigureAuditLogEntity = modelBuilder =>
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomAuditLog>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.CustomProperty).IsRequired();
        });
    };
},
dbContextOptions =>
    dbContextOptions.UseSqlServer("YourConnectionString", sqlOptions =>
    {
        sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly("YourProjectNamespace"); // Replace with your project name
    }));

dotnet ef migrations add "Init" --project <PathToProjectContainingDbContext> --startup-project <PathToStartupProject>


